# How to get the geojson of all features added by Leaflet-geoman

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I'm using Leaflet-geoman to draw circles and polygons in a map.

How can I get the geojson of all features drawn in the map ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all layers of the map you can use this:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup();
map.eachLayer((layer)=>{
   if(layer instanceof L.Path || layer instanceof L.Marker){
    fg.addLayer(layer);
  }
});
console.log(fg.toGeoJSON());
```

If you want only the layers they are used from the plugin:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup();
map.eachLayer((layer)=>{
   if((layer instanceof L.Path || layer instanceof L.Marker) && layer.pm){
    fg.addLayer(layer);
  }
});
console.log(fg.toGeoJSON());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a custom leaflet `featureGroup` which can be fed to geoman. Let's say you are drawing polygons

```
const yourCustomPolygonLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

map.pm.setGlobalOptions({
    layerGroup: yourCustomPolygonLayer
});
```

Now you can iterate over `yourCustomPolygonLayer` easily.

```
yourCustomPolygonLayer.eachLayer(layer => {
    console.info(layer._latlngs)
})
```